# Array to string conversion on File upload functionality in Magento2

Tags: magento2, exception, file-upload

I am getting this error after I put a file upload button.When I click save I got this error

> [2021-01-20 05:42:43] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/M2_arbergtime.dk/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3105
> Trace:
>
> ```
> #1 Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->prepareColumnValue(array('SCHEMA_NAME' => NULL, 'TABLE_NAME' => 'magefan_blog_pos...', 'COLUMN_NAME' => 'blog_header_imag...', 'COLUMN_POSITION' => 36, 'DATA_TYPE' => 'varchar', 'DEFAULT' => NULL, 'NULLABLE' => true, 'LENGTH' => 255, 'SCALE' => NULL, 'PRECISION' => NULL, 'UNSIGNED' => NULL, 'PRIMARY' => false, 'PRIMARY_POSITION' => NULL, 'IDENTITY' => false), array(array('name' => 'magento2.png', 'type' => 'image/png', 'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpWBu1Sw', 'error' => 0, 'size' => 45718, 'file' => 'magento2.png', 'url' => 'http://127.0.0.1...', 'cookie' => array('name' => 'admin', 'value' => 'c0t2uv3r7c197mks...', 'lifetime' => 31536000, 'path' => '/M2_arbergtime.d...', 'domain' => '127.0.0.1'), 'previewType' => 'image', 'id' => 'bWFnZW50bzIucG5n')))
> ```

If i fill some value to image filed in table manually using phpmyadmin, than i git this error in edit page.

`Uncaught TypeError: value.map is not a function
at UiClass.setInitialValue (file-uploader.js:79)`

Answer (score 0):

Follow this post
https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/how-to-upload-image-or-file-in-custom-module-using-ui-component-in-magento-2/

In this post Step 8 should be add in your `DataProvider.php` file

Comment: added this line in etc/di.xml....
    <preference for="Magefan\Blog\Ui\DataProvider\Post\Form\PostDataProvider" type="Kammalou\Blog\Ui\DataProvider\Post\Form\PostDataProvider" />